# lme for multiple groups comparing treatment vs control

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I would like to check for differences in growth rate between groups. I have three main groups `miRs` and for each group I have a `treatment` and a `Neg`. I want to compare treatment vs Neg for all groups. 
Could someone have a look at my setup?
Why is the variable  `mir-135b-5p` nor showing up in the results?

```
> lm <- lme(weight~time*cond, random=~time|miRs, data=testDose)
> anova(lm)
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    38 233748.85  <.0001
time            1    38    398.12  <.0001
cond            3    38      7.14  0.0006
time:cond       3    38      2.34  0.0887
> summary(lm)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: testDose 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  51.94759 72.21414 -13.97379

Random effects:
 Formula: ~time | miRs
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev       Corr  
(Intercept) 3.279719e-06 (Intr)
time        9.458478e-10 0     
Residual    1.951541e-01       

Fixed effects: weight ~ time * cond 
                        Value  Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)         12.322245 0.16900842 38 72.90906  0.0000
time                 0.021713 0.00257138 38  8.44398  0.0000
condmir-21-3p        0.048565 0.23901400 38  0.20319  0.8401
condmir-584-5p       0.125029 0.23901400 38  0.52310  0.6039
condNeg              0.021297 0.19515412 38  0.10913  0.9137
time:condmir-21-3p  -0.002460 0.00363648 38 -0.67658  0.5028
time:condmir-584-5p -0.006198 0.00363648 38 -1.70431  0.0965
time:condNeg         0.001352 0.00296918 38  0.45549  0.6513
 Correlation: 
                    (Intr) time   c-21-3 c-584- condNg t:-21- t:-584
time                -0.913                                          
condmir-21-3p       -0.707  0.645                                   
condmir-584-5p      -0.707  0.645  0.500                            
condNeg             -0.866  0.791  0.612  0.612                     
time:condmir-21-3p   0.645 -0.707 -0.913 -0.456 -0.559              
time:condmir-584-5p  0.645 -0.707 -0.456 -0.913 -0.559  0.500       
time:condNeg         0.791 -0.866 -0.559 -0.559 -0.913  0.612  0.612

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.4935997 -0.5794501 -0.2101814  0.4779404  1.4872837 

Number of Observations: 48
Number of Groups: 3
```

myData

```
> testDose
     weight time        cond        miRs
1  13.10760   24   mir-21-3p   mir-21-3p
2  13.21659   48   mir-21-3p   mir-21-3p
3  13.59320   72   mir-21-3p   mir-21-3p
4  14.18753   96   mir-21-3p   mir-21-3p
5  13.16919   24         Neg   mir-21-3p
6  13.51846   48         Neg   mir-21-3p
7  14.05866   72         Neg   mir-21-3p
8  14.84804   96         Neg   mir-21-3p
9  12.79820   24   mir-21-3p   mir-21-3p
10 13.12730   48   mir-21-3p   mir-21-3p
11 13.69247   72   mir-21-3p   mir-21-3p
12 14.48472   96   mir-21-3p   mir-21-3p
13 12.81832   24         Neg   mir-21-3p
14 13.17344   48         Neg   mir-21-3p
15 13.78877   72         Neg   mir-21-3p
16 14.44471   96         Neg   mir-21-3p
17 13.11672   24 mir-135b-5p mir-135b-5p
18 13.31708   48 mir-135b-5p mir-135b-5p
19 13.78559   72 mir-135b-5p mir-135b-5p
20 14.54087   96 mir-135b-5p mir-135b-5p
21 13.16919   24         Neg mir-135b-5p
22 13.51846   48         Neg mir-135b-5p
23 14.05866   72         Neg mir-135b-5p
24 14.84804   96         Neg mir-135b-5p
25 12.79218   24 mir-135b-5p mir-135b-5p
26 13.18126   48 mir-135b-5p mir-135b-5p
27 13.78006   72 mir-135b-5p mir-135b-5p
28 14.48629   96 mir-135b-5p mir-135b-5p
29 12.81832   24         Neg mir-135b-5p
30 13.17344   48         Neg mir-135b-5p
31 13.78877   72         Neg mir-135b-5p
32 14.44471   96         Neg mir-135b-5p
33 13.06603   24  mir-584-5p  mir-584-5p
34 13.10624   48  mir-584-5p  mir-584-5p
35 13.27287   72  mir-584-5p  mir-584-5p
36 13.96981   96  mir-584-5p  mir-584-5p
37 13.16919   24         Neg  mir-584-5p
38 13.51846   48         Neg  mir-584-5p
39 14.05866   72         Neg  mir-584-5p
40 14.84804   96         Neg  mir-584-5p
41 12.81925   24  mir-584-5p  mir-584-5p
42 13.03732   48  mir-584-5p  mir-584-5p
43 13.59867   72  mir-584-5p  mir-584-5p
44 14.15521   96  mir-584-5p  mir-584-5p
45 12.81832   24         Neg  mir-584-5p
46 13.17344   48         Neg  mir-584-5p
47 13.78877   72         Neg  mir-584-5p
48 14.44471   96         Neg  mir-584-5p
```

Comment: "I want to compare treatment vs Neg for all groups." I don't understand why you use a mixed effects model then. Just do separate tests for each group and adjust the p-values for multiple testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cond` is a factor with 4 values, these are modeled by 3 binary indicator variables, the fourth value corresponds to the 3 binary variables being 0. The baseline is the fourth value and is already accounted for in the intercept and `time` only the deviation from these is expressed for the others.

Comment: But how do I get the p-value for mir-135b-5p

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that.

Comment: @user2300940 mir-135b-5p is collapsed into the intercept, because otherwise the covariance matrix is singular. You have a treatment contrast by default in R, so all the tests you make are comparing to that baseline, i.e. mir-135b-5p, because that is the first level in the factor. You probably want to reorder the levels in the factor, such that Neg is the baseline and compare to that, but I am not sure if that solves your problem. The question you are trying to answer sounds more like anova.

Comment: So maybe put Neg first since its similar for all observations, then put all the different observations (miRs) after?